# Displaying a hypermatrix of uint16 matrices using Matplot

Tags: image-processing, matrix, scilab

I'm trying to write a function in Scilab to display images.
I'm dealing with images as lists of matrices, and then converting the list to a hypermatrix inside the function. However, the code does not seem to work for images of the type uint16 or uint32.
This is the code I've been working on:

**imshow()**

```
function[] =imshow(Image)

global TYPE_DOUBLE;         //retrieving list and creating 3 dimensional matrix out of it
dimensions=size(Image)
MaxUInt8 = 2 ^ 8 - 1;
MaxGrayValue = MaxUInt8; //changed from MaximumGrayValue

if dimensions==3 then 
     matSize=size(Image(1));
     r=matrix(Image(1),matSize(1),matSize(2));
     g=matrix(Image(2),matSize(1),matSize(2));
     b=matrix(Image(3),matSize(1),matSize(2));

     z(:,:,1)=uint8(r);    //Since Matplot is not working with uint16 and uint32, convert every image to a 
     z(:,:,2)=uint8(g);    //8 bit palette.
     z(:,:,3)=uint8(b);    //Note: this will affect the color depth.

     [NumberOfRows NumberOfColumns NumberOfChannels] = size(z);
     NumberOfPixels = NumberOfRows * NumberOfColumns;
     Sample = z(1);

     //printf("\nType of Sample: ");
 //printf(typeof(Sample)); //DEBUG: 
     //printf("\n");    

if type(Sample) == 1 then //type 1 = real/complex matrix of double
         ColorMap = matrix(z, NumberOfPixels, NumberOfChannels);
         disp(ColorMap); 
     else
        TypeName = typeof(Sample)
         select TypeName
             case 'uint8' 
                MaxGrayValue = 2 ^ 8 - 1;
        //printf("uint8\t%d", MaxGrayValue); //DEBUG:
             case 'uint16'
                MaxGrayValue = 2 ^ 16 - 1;
        //ColorMap = double(matrix(z, NumberOfPixels, NumberOfChannels)) / MaxGrayValue;
        //printf("uint16\t%d", MaxGrayValue); //DEBUG:
             case 'uint32'
                MaxGrayValue = 2 ^ 32 - 1;
            //ColorMap = double(matrix(z, NumberOfPixels, NumberOfChannels)) / MaxGrayValue;
        //printf("uint32\t%d", MaxGrayValue); //DEBUG:
     end;  
     ColorMap = double(matrix(z, NumberOfPixels, NumberOfChannels)) / MaxGrayValue;
 printf("\nCreated colormap with MaxGrayValue = %d\n", MaxGrayValue); //DEBUG:
     end;       
     Img=z;

 //Grayscale
 elseif dimensions==1 then
     matSize = size(Image(1));
     Img=matrix(Image(1),matSize(1),matSize(2));
     Img=Img';
     select typeof(Img)
         case 'uint8' 
            MaxGrayValue = MaxUInt8;
         case 'uint16'  
            MaxGrayValue = max(Image(:)) ;
         case 'uint32' 
            MaxGrayValue = max(Image(:));                
    end;
 ColorMap = graycolormap(double(MaxGrayValue + 1)); //changed from MaximumGrayValue
 end;
 show(Img,ColorMap);
endfunction
```

**show()**

```
function[] =show(Img,ColorMap) 

     FigureHandle = gcf();
     drawlater();
     FigureHandle.color_map = ColorMap
     FigureHandle.background = -2; // sets the background to white
     FigureHandle.figure_name = "Title";
     [NumberOfRows NumberOfColumns] = size(Img);
     FigureHandle.axes_size = [NumberOfColumns NumberOfRows];

     delete(gca()); // previous image is deleted
     Diagram = gca();
     [NumberOfRows NumberOfColumns] = size(Img);
     Diagram.data_bounds = [1, 1; NumberOfColumns, NumberOfRows];
     Diagram.axes_visible = ['off' 'off' 'off'];
     Diagram.isoview = 'on';
     Options = '082'; // Box is drawn around image.


     //printf("\nGiven to Matplot: "); //DEBUG:
     //printf(typeof(Img));        //DEBUG: 
     Matplot(Img, Options); 
     drawnow();

 endfunction
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
 !--error 202 
 Matplot: Wrong type for input argument #1: A real or integer      expected.
 at line      22 of function show called by :  
 at line      67 of function imshow called by :  
 imshow(a);
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Please add your code here instead of linking to an external source.

Comment: What do you mean with: " the code does not seem to work for images of the type uint16 or uint32." Do you have specific error messages?

Comment: Yes, I do. I'll edit the original post.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that OpenCV and matplotlib all cannot support imshow of uint16 or uint32, so the images will be converted to uint8 when shown.